# php: writing a script function

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple question about php. In PHP, can we have script function, javascript or any other script in php section **without** script tag. Something like this:

```
<?php
    function javascript_or_any_other_script_function() {
    }
?>
```

I am aware that the question is pretty naive (almost silly) but I wanted to see whether php supports this syntax.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: yes.But  its act like a [php function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp)

Comment: what are you trying to do basically? could you please tell us your requirement, may be we could find a better way for you.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is in the server, JavaScript is in the browser...

To get JavaScript in client(browser), you need to output it in php...

```
function javascript_function() {

return 'function foo() {alert("working");}';

}

print('<script>');
print( javascript_function() );
print('</script>')
```

Comment: if I understand correctly "javascript_function" is function written in PHP (and foo is in javascript). Would that mean I can never write a javascript function out in open, without quotes, and without script tags in php? sorry, as I said, it's very naive question.